# Chinese characters all become gibberish when using pandas read_stata() function

Tags: python, pandas, stata

I'm trying to read a Stata .dta file with the python pandas package, using the read_stata() function, and the dta file has many Chinese characters in it. The file read in was all messed up codes, and the Chinese characters were all just gibberish. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please add what is the code you are using ? And what is the output you are getting?

Comment: Perhaps you could show us what kind of data you have and what it looks like when Pandas has read it? That can tell us a lot about what kind of codec would be needed.

Comment: I didn't specify the right encoding at the first try(I tried unicode), because I didn't know what encodings are available there. gb2312 seems to be the right one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to specify a codec to use, the default is to decode your text as ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1):

```
pandas.read_stata(filename, encoding=codec_to_use)
```

See the [`pandas.read_stata()` documenation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_stata.html):

> **encoding**: *string, None or encoding*
>   Encoding used to parse the files. Note that Stata doesn’t support unicode. `None` defaults to iso-8859-1.

For Chinese, I'd *guess* that the codec used is either a `gb*` codec (`gb18030`, `gbk`, `gb2312`) or a UTF codec (`UTF-8`, `UTF-16`, or `UTF-32`). In spite of the remark in the Panda's documenation above, I see that [Stata 14 supports Unicode now](http://blog.stata.com/tag/unicode/), and that they use UTF-8 for that.

Also see the [*Standard Encodings* page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) for an overview of supported codecs.

Comment: Thanks! I read the read_stata document and didn't find the encoding list, then I tried my luck at the read_csv document, and found the encoding list as you directed. gb2312 works:)